# same menu different activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to show the same menu (made with imageviews) on all my activies, and I try:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView iv1;
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        iv1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
    }

    ...
}
```

and the others activities looks like:

```
public class PlayersActivity extends BaseActivity {
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

But, the activities don't see the ImageView that I defined on the BaseActivity.
I have a null object with the imageview.

Answer (score 2):

iv1 will always be null, in the base activity or the subclass, because you never called `setContentView`